# Why is there only one solution to this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous such that $f(x,y)<0$ if $xy>0$ and $f(x,y)>0$ if $xy<0$. Show that the following initial value problem has an unique solution

\begin{align}
y'=f(x,y),\quad y(0)=0
\end{align}

One solution is obviously $y(x)\equiv 0$, since $f(x,0)=0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ because of continuity. I have problems to argue that there can't be another solution. Usually one knows uniqueness if the RHS is locally Lipschitz continuous which is not the case here. How can one prove the uniqueness?

Best wishes

Comment: Can you say that you know one solution is y=0 and by the uniqueness of initial value problems, this is the only solution?

Comment: I was not sure, why the solution must be unique?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y : [0,T) \to \mathbb R$ be such a solution. For each $S<T$, let $m_s$ and $M_s$ be the minimum and the maximum value of $y$ in $[0,S]$. If $y$ is not idenitically zero, then either one of them is not zero.

First assume $M_S>0$. Then there is $t\in [0,S]$ so that $y(t) = M_S$. Thus either $y'(t) = 0$ or $t = S$. The first case is impossible by the condition of $f$. For the latter case is also not possible: as a maximum on the endpoint, $y'(S) \ge 0$ and it again contradicts the assumption on $f$.

Thus $M_s = 0$ for all $S$, similarly one show that $m_s$ for all $S$. Thus $y$ is the zero function.

Comment: Your arguments look great, thank you! Could you please explain the logic of your sentence: " For the latter case is also not possible as$ y>0$ on $[S−ϵ,S]$, this force $y′<0$ on this interval."

Comment: @asd: The argument is actually easier, please see the edit.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much again! :-)